# Numpy remove rows with same column values

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

How do I remove rows from ndarray arrays which have the same nth column value?

For eg,

```
a = np.ndarray([[1, 3, 4],
     [1, 3, 4],
     [1, 3, 5]])
```

And I want to have rows unique by third column.
I want to have just the `[1, 3, 5]` row left.

`numpy.unique` does not do it. It will check for uniqueness in every column; I can't specify the
column by which to check uniqueness.

How can I do this efficiently for thousand + rows?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a combination of [bincount](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html), [nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) and [in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 3, 4],
    [1, 3, 4],
    [1, 3, 5]])

#A tuple containing the values which are unique in column 3
unique_in_column = (np.bincount(a[:,2]) == 1).nonzero()

a[:,2] == unique_in_column[0]
unique_index = np.in1d(a[:,2], unique_in_column[0])

unique_a = a[unique_index]
```

This should do the trick. However, I'm not sure how this method scales with 1000+ rows.

Comment: `unique_in_column = (np.bincount(a[:,2]) == 1).nonzero()` doesn't work for ndarray of floats. I have ndarray of floats.

Answer (score 0):

I had done this finally:

```
repeatdict = {}
todel = []
for i, row in enumerate(kplist):
    if repeatdict.get(row[2], 0):
        todel.append(i)
    else:
        repeatdict[row[2]] = 1
kplist = np.delete(kplist, todel, axis=0)
```

Basically, I iterated over the list store the values of the third column, and if in the next iteration the same value is already found in the `repeatdict` dict, that row is marked for deletion, by storing its index in `todel` list.

Then we can get rid of the unwanted rows by calling np.delete with the list of all row indexes which we want to delete.

Also, I'm not picking my answer as the picked answer, because I know there's probably a better way to do this with just numpy magic.
I'll wait.